# Webpage is not displayed properly in outlook

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, outlook

when i try to send a webpage via email using the "send page by E-mail" menu in the internet explorer, the webpage is not displayed properly.

On the webpage we have javascript enabled dropdown menus that impact the layout of the page.

is there any special coding for outlook editor so that it will appear the same as in ie?

-Vivek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use JavaScripting or any scripting of any kind inside email messages. Most servers will outright deny messages with scripting of any kind in them for fear of it being a hacking attempt, but if by chance you get past the email server with your message the client will surely strip the scripting out. So no you can't send JavaScript menus in email, you must use basic HTML 4.01 with in-line CSS to get the best cross-client results on the display and readability of your HTML Email Messages.